# MiniTest::Unit::TestCase Functions

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am learning watir-webdriver. And I have this code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'minitest/autorun'


class Login < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_in()



      browser =Watir::Browser.new
      browser.goto 'just testing'
      accept_next_alert=true


              browser.text_field(:name => 'username').set('admin')
              browser.text_field(:name => 'password').set('admin')
              browser.button(:name => 'login').click


          sleep 3
          browser.link(:text => 'Dashboard').click
          browser.link(:href => '/user/').click

          sleep 5
          browser.button(:class => 'btn btn-add').click


    end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    text_field(how, what)
    true
  rescue Watir::Browser::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def alert_present?()
    switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue Watir::Browser::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue MiniTest::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = switch_to().alert()
    alert_text = alert.text
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end

end

init1=Login
```

I am just confuse with these 4 other functions: element_present?, alert_present?, verify, and close_alert_and_get_its_text.. Actually these codes are being exported from selenium IDE  to Ruby/Test::Unit/Webdriver. And I want to use Watir-webdriver as my tool. Can somebody tell me how these functions works with watir-webdriver or how can I reuse them... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir already has methods for the things you are trying to do.  Unlike selenium, Watir uses an object model based on HTML and the browser DOM. So the normal pattern is to do things along the lines of `browser.object(:how => "what).method` This allows (what I consider anyway) a more proper OOP style where you ask objects about themselves "hey text_box, are you present?" instead of asking one object about another object "hey browser, is there a text_box present?", or tell them to act upon themselves ala `browser.button(:text => 'click me!').click`  (what's happening there is we use the  browser's .button method, which returns a button object, then we are calling the button object's .click method)

So things like 'element_present?' and 'alert_present" just become a `.present?` method you invoke via the appropriate object.  Most objects have all the methods you would expect, both for generic html elements, and specific objects like form inputs having .set methods  see the [docs on .check_box for an example](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/CheckBox)

[.present?](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#present%3F-instance_method)  returns true element exists and is visible

Example, if you have warning text that appears if someone tries to proceed without agreeing to your terms and conditions, you might validate this using code such as:

`assert browser.div(:class => 'toc_warning').present?`

Also have a look at the .when_present decorator. Use it like this instead of fixed sleeps when waiting for JS code to render an object before trying to act on the object:

```
browser.link(:text => 'Dashboard').when_present.click
```

[.exists?](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#exists%3F-instance_method)  returns true if element exists within the DOM

the [alert object](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert) has methods to do what you want with alerts such as capturing alert text and responding to alerts.  it also supports the methods above.  That would allow you to do something like this presuming a moment when the script expects an alert to appear:

```
alert_text = browser.alert.when_present.text
browser.alert.ok  #or use .close instead of .ok depending
```

As to the verify method, watir is really about driving the browser, it is not trying to be a test framework so has no methods of that sort.  The expectation is that you would use something like rSpec, Cucumber, MiniTest, etc and make use of whatever style of assertion is typical your choice of framework.  Since most of those take care of reportng errors, even stack traces, when assertions fail, I've never had need for a wrapper around that stuff. But if you need such a thing, go for it, the code you had above seems on the right track for that sort of thing.